# How does bitwise & and << help in this subset problem?

Tags: javascript, arrays, bit-manipulation, subset

I am learning how to print all the subsets with same length in Javascript. And I saw [this solution](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-function-exercise-21.php) on w3resource.com:

> #### JavaScript Function: Exercise-21 with Solution
>
> ---
>
> Write a JavaScript function to get all possible subset with a fixed length (for example 2) combinations in an array.
>
> *Sample array :* `[1, 2, 3]` and subset length is 2
>
> *Expected output :* `[[2, 1], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]`
>
> **JavaScript Code:**
>
> ```
> function subset(arra, arra_size) {
>     var result_set = [], 
>         result;
>     for(var x = 0; x < Math.pow(2, arra.length); x++) {
>         result = [];
>         i = arra.length - 1; 
>         do {
>             if( (x & (1 << i)) !== 0) {
>                 result.push(arra[i]);
>             }
>         }  while(i--);
>         if( result.length >= arra_size) {
>             result_set.push(result);
>         }
>     }
>
>     return result_set; 
> }
> ```

However I don't understand to logic behind the code especially the line with the bitwise operator. Could anyone explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(x & (1 << i)) !== 0` means "does `x` have the `i`<sup>th</sup> bit set to 1?"

An example:

Let's say `x` in binary representation is 1001101

And let `i` go from 6 down to 0 (which is what the `do` loop does)

Then we get:

| `i` | `1 << i` (binary) | `x & (1 << i)` (binary) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1000000 | 1000000 |
| 5 | 100000 | 0 |
| 4 | 10000 | 0 |
| 3 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 10 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |

The outer loop will produce all possible binary bit patterns with as many digits as there are values in the array.

This way, those bit patterns (`x`) actually describe all possible subsets of the array (a 1 bit means: include the corresponding array value, a 0 means: don't include it). The bit shift operator helps to *isolate* one bit in the bit pattern, so to decide whether or not to include the corresponding array value.

See MDN for the documentation on [Bitwise AND (`&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND) and [Left shift (`<<`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Left_shift)